# How to code a simple forward propagation of recurrent neural networks?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, numpy, rnn

I know the theory behind recurrent neural networks or RNN but I am confused about its implementation. This is an rnn equation I got from the web,
[image]

I tried to code the forward propagation alone in python's numpy

```
import numpy as np

outputs = 5
inputs = 3

# Input value
# (batch_size,seq_len, vocab_len)
X = np.ones((10,3,3))


# Initializing rnn weights and hidden states
Wxh = np.random.rand(outputs,inputs)
Whh = np.random.rand(outputs,inputs)
Why = np.random.rand(outputs,inputs)
h = np.zeros((1,inputs))

# Forward propagation
def rnn(x,h):
    h = np.tanh(np.dot(Whh,h.T) + np.dot(Wxh,x.T))
    y = np.dot(Why,h.T)
    return y,h

for i in X:
    _,h = rnn(i,h)
```

But I get a broadcasting error. How do we implement the forward propogation of rnn?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, what does the forward pass of a RNN look like. You read about using the inputs plus values from the previous node (here it will be prev_s)
First initialise the weights, than perform the foreward pass. I highlighted what you was looking for.

```
U = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, T))
W = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (hidden_dim, hidden_dim))
V = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (output_dim, hidden_dim))


 for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
        x, y = X[i], Y[i]

        layers = []
        prev_s = np.zeros((hidden_dim, 1))
        dU = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dV = np.zeros(V.shape)
        dW = np.zeros(W.shape)

        dU_t = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dV_t = np.zeros(V.shape)
        dW_t = np.zeros(W.shape)

        dU_i = np.zeros(U.shape)
        dW_i = np.zeros(W.shape)

        # forward pass
        for t in range(T):
            new_input = np.zeros(x.shape)
            new_input[t] = x[t]
            mulu = np.dot(U, new_input)
            mulw = np.dot(W, prev_s)
            add = mulw + mulu
            s = sigmoid(add)
            ***mulv = np.dot(V, s)***
            layers.append({'s':s, 'prev_s':prev_s})
            prev_s = s
```

So the '***  ***' area can be roughly translated: mulv = np.dot(V, s) are the weights multiplied with the current state. (same as before, s==input_vector) but the difference is that the s will be calculated with weights from previous output and current input i.e.

```
mulu = np.dot(U, new_input)
mulw = np.dot(W, prev_s)
add = mulw + mulu
s = sigmoid(add)
```

Thats why we have 3 initial weights in the first place.